# Android can't create an instance ViewModel in java

Tags: android, database, android-jetpack

I have followed the codelab of google for room database and other components, but when I try to play the application gives me someone error. I read the doc of ViewModel and I try to use a Factory to create the Instance, but it's the same result. Pls, help me.

This is the error in the bash:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.presenze, PID: 25619
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.presenze/com.example.presenze.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.presenze.UtenteViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.presenze.UtenteViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at com.example.presenze.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7088)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7079)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.presenze.UtenteViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.example.presenze.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7088) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7079) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25619 SIG: 9
```

this is the link for git: https://github.com/itakartor/Presenze.git

Comment: Try to update your `appCompat` version in your build.gradle to as follows and try again. `appCompatVersion = '1.3.0-rc01'` This is a known issue of codelabs and I have raised a PR regarding same.

Comment: ty u now works!
Now startActivityForResult is deprecate and all don't work.
hint for solution?